# Java Frame... not focusing on JTextField

Tags: java

Whenever my Applet starts up.. I start it as Java application and here's what I do:

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Game - v2.2");
    applet=new tileOffline();
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.requestFocusInWindow();
    frame.getContentPane().add(applet,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(646,558);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
       {public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt)
         { applet.stop(); applet.destroy(); System.exit(0); 
       } } );

    applet.init();
    applet.start();    
    frame.setVisible(true);
    say.setFocusable(true);
    say.setText("Test");
  }
```

So when I start the game... when you first press any key... it should go in the `JTextField` of `say` because it's focused on that. But nope. It's not.

In fact, it sees `say` because it successfully adds `Test` to `say`... so... I dunno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling

```
say.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `WindowAdapter`

```
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
   say.requestFocus();
}
```

Cheers,